# Graphql Multiple enums in query

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I'd like to set up a query that has multiple enums sent over for the same parameter.

```
test_query(enum:FIRST,SECOND){
  stuffs
}
```

It appears that this is not possible in graphql-JS, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You simply wrap them in `[]`

```
test_query(enum:[FIRST,SECOND]){
  stuffs
}
```

Comment: Note you must also modify your schema to accept a GraphQLList of GraphQLEnumType

Comment: No, you actually don't. ENUMs are sets of named values.

Comment: Interesting! Will retest, perhaps I was running into another issue.

Comment: how is this accomplished using the javascript notation?

Comment: Actually, I was wrong. You need to wrap it in `GraphQLList`, but once you've done it's not mandatory to send the enum as a list. You can do simply `enum: FIRST` even though it expects a set.

Comment: in ruby you do: `argument :myfieldname, types[Types::MyFieldENUM], "description"`